# What is the average color of a star?

Tags: procedural-generation

I am trying to procedurally generate point stars to create a starfield background for my game. I want to weight the color production based on an average star's real color. Can anyone point me in the direction of this sort of data?

Comment: In case you don't get many answers here (or, if you get closed) - you could try this: http://payload42.com/ it's a bit quiet though.

Comment: Whew that was close, looks like the question will remain open. That is, if no one else will vote on it...

Comment: How the heck is this off-topic, but "what's your favorite web-cartoon" isn't? Open this question again. It's more than enough related to multi-sampling and signal theory.

Comment: If users with admin privileges likes to moderate, they can start with subjective questions, not questions like these.

Comment: @Mads Elvheim: Thanks for the support, but looks like it's staying closed. I got my answer anyway, so it wasn't a complete failure.

Comment: @RCIX: Good to hear. You might also mix those colors to mimic several stars (cluster) at one pixel. It would more or less be the same as multisampling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a nice overview [here](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/starcolor/). It shows some real examples. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: This is exactly what i need, and if i can accept it in time i will do so! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is White. To be closer to the real thing apply redshift as the stars are further away and add or remove blue to account for star temperature and age.

Comment: I didn't think of applying redshift, thanks :)